# Having problems with connecting to/seeing the local SQL server with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql

I'm having some difficulties when I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server. 
I'm pretty sure the server is running (many of the other topics on this subject suggests that the services might not be running, so I kinda looked into it, but they do seem to be running).

But when I try to access it through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it doesn't seem to be able to find them.

Server type: Database Engine

Server name: ILIZANESQL* -> I'm trying to "browse for more..." to find my server, but it doesn't show up

Authentication: Windows Authentication

Comment: i don't know if this matters, but i have an SQLEXPRESS and my ILIZANESQL servers running.. but i can't connect to any of them :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(local)
```

for the server name

Comment: tried that, but didn't work, it recommend that by itself though, but didn't find it.

Comment: if it helps in anyway my friend weren't able to find it on my network, nor could i connect to it through Visual Studio 2010

Comment: based on your comment above try...(local)/SQLEXPRESS or (local)/ILIZANESQL

Comment: doesn't work.

But it says that I have to check my spelling and also if my SQL server allows remote connections. Can I see if that is enabled? (even though it seems weird that it should be the problem when its local)
Is there anything that i need to do other then installing it and making sure its running? its kinda frustrating because last i installed it, it worked just fine.

Comment: Can you list exactly what SQL services are running on the machine?

Comment: - SQL Server Integration Services 10.0
- SQL Server (ILIZANESQL)
- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (ILIZANESQL)
- SQL Server Agent(ILIZANESQL)
- SQL Server Agent(SQLEXPRESS) cannot start this, as start mode is set to other(Boot,System,Disabled or Unkown)
- SQL Server Browser

Comment: I just tried turning everything on again. Ehm. And now i can find both of them under my network servers and they do seem to work as intended. 

is there any good and easy understanding books on how to run and maintain a SQL server? By the way, thanks alot for the help :P

Comment: Give this one a look http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Server-2008-Express-Developers/dp/1430210907

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log in Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL/Log. What is the errorlog file showing as the listener when SQL Server started.

You should have information in there like:

2011-01-14 06:41:31.90 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].
2011-01-14 06:41:31.90 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].

Is the SQL Express? There might be a named instance as well. I would potentially check that you don't need .\SQLExpress as the name.

You can also run SQL Configuration Manager and set a specific port for a named instance and then use 127.0.0.1, port

Check that the Windows firewall is allowing connections